# Gutenberg Richtext generating "&#xFEFF" in editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, rich-text-editor, richtextblock

[image]I have used rich text element of Gutenberg, in editor i found this kind of entity coming when we are editing - https://prnt.sc/uqJZokTorIK_ , that is creating issue in layout, when we click its showing blank space.

```
/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import { RichText, useBlockProps } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { Platform } from "@wordpress/element";

export default function edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
  const {circleHeadline,circleText} = attributes;

  const blockProps = useBlockProps({
        className: 'visual-circle__item',
    });

  const onTitleChange = (value) => {
    const newTitle = { circleHeadline: value };
    setAttributes(newTitle);
  };

  const onTextChange = (value) => {
    const newText = { circleText: value };
    setAttributes(newText);
  };

  return (
    <li {...blockProps}>
      <RichText
        identifier="circleHeadline"
        tagName="span"
        className="visual-circle__title"
        value={circleHeadline}
        onChange={onTitleChange}
        withoutInteractiveFormatting={true}
        aria-label={__("Main Text")}
        placeholder={__("Lorem")}
        {...(Platform.isNative && { deleteEnter: true })} // setup RichText on native mobile to delete the "Enter" key as it's handled by the JS/RN side
        allowedFormats={[""]}
      />
      <RichText
        identifier="circleText"
        tagName="span"
        className="visual-circle__text"
        value={circleText}
        onChange={onTextChange}
        withoutInteractiveFormatting={true}
        aria-label={__("Sub Text")}
        placeholder={__("Nullam dictum eu pede")}
        {...(Platform.isNative && { deleteEnter: true })} // setup RichText on native mobile to delete the "Enter" key as it's handled by the JS/RN side
        allowedFormats={[""]}
      />
    </li>
    );
}
```

I have tried diffrent tag instead of span tag in rich text but issue is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue, i found that this character is coming in core blocks rich text element also, the issue in my code is i used span tag with display block css.